# Intercalar valores de um Array em javaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, eu preciso intercalar um vetor com o maior numero, depois o menor, depois o maior...
Ex: [2, 10, 5, 3]deverá retornar [10, 2, 5, 3]
Segue abaixo o código que fiz:

```html
function shuffleMusicas(musicasTocadas) {
  let musicas = [2, 10, 5, 3];
  musicas.sort((a,b) => b - a) ;

  console.log( musicas)
}
```

Comment: Primeiro ordene a lista. Depois, construa a lista nova pegando o último elemento, depois o primeiro, o penúltimo, o segundo, e assim por diante...

Comment: Outra coisa, sua função recebe `musicasTocadas`, mas ignora completamente este parâmetro e cria um novo array dentro dela. Está errado, o certo é usar o array `musicasTocadas` e passar um array qualquer ao chamar a função. Sobre a resposta abaixo, o problema dela é que o array original é modificado ([veja](https://ideone.com/b7S0J0)), o que nem sempre pode ser o desejável. Enfim, uma forma de fazer seria: https://ideone.com/Xfpq1m - e só pra ser chato, "shuffle" significa "embaralhar", mas vc não está embaralhando de fato. Vc está colocando em uma ordem específica, com regras bem definidas

Answer (score 0):

Podes começar por ordenar o array, depois percorre-lo e em cada iteração adicionar o primeiro e último elementos a um novo array. Algo como isto:

```js
const shuffleSongs = (playedSongs) => {
  const sortedSongs = playedSongs.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  const suffledSongs = [];
  
  while (sortedSongs.length > 0) {
    suffledSongs.push(sortedSongs.shift());
    sortedSongs.length && suffledSongs.push(sortedSongs.pop());
  }
  
  return suffledSongs;
}

console.log(shuffleSongs([2, 10, 5, 3]));
```